# What is the difference between start(noun) and starting?

Tags: synonyms, vocabulary

I'd like to know the difference between *start* and *starting* when use as a noun.
I saw the following sentence and could not understand why it shold be "to starting" instead of "to start".

> He is looking forward to starting his job next week.

Comment: @All Don't answer in comments. Write an answer (especially if you think mine could be improved).

Answer (score 2):

*Look forward to* requires a noun, as you know. The gerund *starting* is a verb form which functions as a noun, so "look forward to starting" is correct. The *to* here is not a particle in a verb; it's a preposition, and the preposition licenses only a noun.

*Start* is a noun as well as a verb; a race has a start and an end. However, a peculiarity of English nouns (as opposed to, say, Russian) is that they usually require some sort of determiner.

So one **might** say "He's looking forward to **the start** of his job next week," but that does mean something subtly different from the original "starting his job".

Comment: I'm writing this in an attempt to get you to make your post at least less confusing, if not more accurate. And to ask for clarification. You say *look forward to* requires a **noun**. But then you say that *starting* is a **verb form** and is correct. So does *look forward to* require a noun or does it accept verbs? And you say that *to* licences only a noun. But you say that *starting* is a verb. And *to starting* is correct. Can you unmuddle this muddle for us please? :-/

Comment: *Starting* is a verb form which functions as a noun. I don't see what's unclear about that. You are, of course, at liberty to write a better answer.

Comment: When you say *lft* requires a noun, do you mean it cannot take a verb?

Answer (score 1):

> He is looking forward to starting his job next week.

***To*** there is a preposition that normally requires a noun as its complement. It can also take a **gerund** (verb+ing) because a preposition can **generally license a gerund****(*** i.e. starting ***)** as opposed to other classes of verbs.( A gerund is close to a noun). Still, ***starting*** is a **verb** and that's the reason why it can take ***his job*** as its own object.

> He is looking forward to start his job next week.

This one is ungrammatical. Preposition ***to*** cannot license this form of verb.

But ***start*** is a noun if preceded by a determiner like *the* and takes an *of phrase complement* as exemplified in Andrew Leach's example.

> He's looking forward to the start of his job next week.

Comment: Does *starting* in *starting his job* have any noun type properties at all? For example, can it be modified by an adjective? Maybe if you want to use a verb after a preposition you have to use an -*ing* form of the verb (and thus the verb has verb-type properties, because it’s a verb)?  (+1, but I think the noun-type properties might cause readers problems!)

Comment: Happy I got a +1 from you! My initial reasoning is that since "looking forward to" can take "starting" as its complement and it is grammatical, that would imply that "starting" has the property of a noun though overall it is a verb because of its direct object "his job." (Nouns normally cannot take a direct object like that.) Would that make sense? Thank you for your feedback. I'm happy to improve my answer but right now I need to take my lunch. @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. done my lunch and my edit.  You can pass judgment on it a second time. :)

Answer (score -1):

The "to" in "looking forward to" is a preposition, and requires a noun phrase after.

While both "start" and "starting" can be used as nouns, they are used with different structures.

The noun "start" cannot have a direct object like "his job". The word "start" can only have a direct object if it is a verb, so "*start his job*" is always verb phrase, never a noun phrase, which means it cannot follow the preposition "to".

The gerund "starting", however, is a verb acting as a noun, so it can have a direct object, so "*starting his job*" is a valid noun phrase, and it can come after the preposition "to".

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Thanks. How do you like my edit?

Comment: Thanks. Hmm. I think it’s still pretty confusing, but maybe that’s me. For example the verb *start* (which is the same verb as the verb *starting*) can only be a verb phrase and not a noun phrase in *start his job* because it takes a direct object. Ok, but hang on: *starting* takes a direct object in *starting his job*, but you say it is *not*  a verb phrase and it ***is*** a noun phrase.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. I'm open to suggestions. You seem to get what I'm trying to express, so how would you word it?